# how to change swiper-button-prev and next color with swiper in Ruby on rails 7?

Tags: swiper.js, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I want to change swiper-button-prev and next color with swiper in Ruby on rails 7

## My html code

```
            <swiper-container navigation="true" pagination="true" scrollbar="true" effect="coverflow" loop="true">
                <swiper-slide>
                    <div class="mpla">Slide 1 </div>
                </swiper-slide>
                <swiper-slide>
                    <div class="mpla">Slide 2 </div>
                </swiper-slide>
                <swiper-slide>
                    <div class="mpla">slide 3 </div>
                </swiper-slide>
                <swiper-slide>
                    <div class="mpla">Slide 4 </div>
                </swiper-slide>


            </swiper-container>
```

## My css code that is not working

```
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  color: #330023;
}
```

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/element#injecting-styles